# MySQL quotes gets garbled despite using html_entity_decode

Tags: php, mysql

My mysql table hold the text

```
you'd
```

But when I fetch this value using php and display it, my browser shows it as

```
 you�d
```

I'm using html_entity_decode

```
$answer = html_entity_decode($row['faq_ans']);
```

But I still don't see the quotes.

Comment: Did you check, if it is returned correctly from the database?

Comment: Check that your `content-type` encodings match on your display page. Try changing it to `UTF-8`, for instance. But what you save should mirror what you output.

Comment: It returns the quote just fine in MySQL workbench

Comment: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: in my php file the charset is set to utf-8, and in mysql workbench, the char set for the schema is `utf8 - default collation`

Comment: Then it could be however you're inputting it into your database is not matching UTF-8.

Comment: What does `SELECT HEX(faq_ans) FROM <yourtable>` gives you for this particular row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want the converse of html_entity_decode() - htmlentities().

Also, iconv() is what I usually use for character-to-character conversion.